# Handling Properties When There Are Multiple Contraints

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm trying to build a reusable Angular Material table that holds different arrays (different meaning, their interfaces are slightly different). So far, I have...

```
export class ReusableTable<T extends DataA | DataB | DataC> {
    @Input() public dataArr: T[] = [];
    public dataSource! = MatTableDataSource<T>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataArr);
    }

    public getTransactionTotal(): number {
        return this.dataArr.map(t => t.transactionAmount).reduce((acc: number, value: number) => acc + value, 0);
    }
}
```

The component holds each array just fine. However, the method getTransactionTotal() throws an error since not all of the Interfaces the component extends has a transactionAmount property.

```
interface DataA {
    transactionDate: Date;
    username: string;
    transactionAmount: number;
}

interface DataB {
    payerFirstName: string;
    payerLastName: string;
    monthlyTotal: number;
}

interface DataC {
    organization: string;
    username: string;
    transactionAmount: number;
}
```

I'm wondering if there's some way around this. I could possibly utilize different generic variables (i.e. T extends DataA | DataC, U extends DataB), but that would require me to build multiple tables in this component, which can get a little crazy. The project I'm working on actually has quite a few more interfaces to take into account and this is actually just a simplified example.

Comment: If t.transactionAmount could be undefined I.e. type DataB then you need to handle that. Doesn’t just sound like a typescript issue. E.g. via coalescing `t.transactionAmount ?? 0`

Comment: I was attempting a check to see if the property exists, but Typescript will still give me an error since it does not recognize transactionAmount as an existing property in one of the constraints. I'm sure it's more of an issue with the techniques I'm using, but just not sure how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing the interface with the optional property `?` option. Like shown below.

```
interface DataA {
    transactionDate: Date;
    username: string;
    transactionAmount?: number; // <- changed here
}

interface DataB {
    payerFirstName: string;
    payerLastName: string;
    monthlyTotal: number;
}

interface DataC {
    organization: string;
    username: string;
    transactionAmount?: number; // <- changed here
}
```